# Regex: removing characters after a "/" in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have some text that has been tagged using an NLP library:

```
text = "I/PRP guess/VBP my/PRP$ point/NN that/IN I/PRP be/VBD try/VBG to/TO communicate/VB ,/, be/VBZ how/WRB do/VBP these/DT pedo/NN ring/NNS get/VBP so/RB big/JJ before/IN they/PRP be/VBP expose/VBN ./."
```

and I have the words:

```
words = ["my", "I"]
```

I want to find all occurrences of `words in` text` and for that part I have:

```
pattern = r'\W.*?({})\W.*?'.format('|'.join(words))
s = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but first I need to ignore the parts that are after "/", otherwise nothing matches. How can I do so?

Comment: Use this instead `r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(words))`.

Comment: You can use `/.+? `([link](https://regex101.com/r/gG0lfK/1/)) to remove all unwanted parts.

Comment: if you just want to select the occurences of these words something like this might help ```\b(?:my|I)\/``` or if you want to use join do it like ```r'\b((?:{}))\/'.format('|'.join(words))``` all your matches are now in group 1. see here https://regex101.com/r/8JMPSP/2

Answer (score 0):

I am not shure, if the following regex works without modifications with the python regex engine. I used the regex implementation of .NET in my tests.

To find all specified words use the regex:
`\b(my|I)\b`

If you want to ignore all matches of the words where a `/` is the previous character, you can add an negative look-behind `(?<!/)`.
`\b(?<!/)(my|I)\b`

`\b` is the start or end of a word.